# menu marcado conforme a pagina com php

Tags: php

alguem tem alguma ideia de como posso deixar o menu marcado conforme a pagina do usuario, fiz de um jeito aqui, porem e muita verificaçao, levando em conta que eu tenho varias paginas, vo posta de como eu fiz

```
if(isset($urlE[1]) && $urlE[1] == 'a'){
    echo '
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'" style="width:45px;border-radius:2px;">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ativo">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/b">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/c">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/d">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/e">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/f">F</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/g">G</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/h">H</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/i">I</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/j">J</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/k">K</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/l">L</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/m">M</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/n">N</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/o">O</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/p">P</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/q">Q</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/r">R</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/s">S</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/t">T</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/u">U</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/v">V</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/w">W</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/x">X</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/y">Y</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/z">Z</a></li>
    ';
}elseif(isset($urlE[1]) && $urlE[1] == 'b'){
    echo '
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'" style="width:45px;border-radius:2px;">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/a">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ativo">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/c">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/d">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/e">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/f">F</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/g">G</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/h">H</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/i">I</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/j">J</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/k">K</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/l">L</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/m">M</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/n">N</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/o">O</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/p">P</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/q">Q</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/r">R</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/s">S</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/t">T</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/u">U</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/v">V</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/w">W</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/x">X</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/y">Y</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$urlBase.'/filtragem/z">Z</a></li>
    ';
}
```

e assim em diante, tem como fazer que fique mais limpo? tem que ser em php, porque a pagina da refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente isso (ajuste as variáveis):

```
for ($i=0; $i < 26; $i++) {
   $letra=Chr(97+$i);

   if ($urlAtual == $letra) {
      echo "<html do $letra SELECIONADO>";
   } else {
      echo "<html do $letra normal>";
   }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/brbUe4)**.

A função `Chr` gera um caractere conforme a tabela ASCII (97 é o `a`);

Se for usar uma lista de palavras em vez de letras:

```
$palavras = ['suspense','acao','terror','educativo-xxx','comedia','documentario'];

foreach ($palavras as $palavra) {
   if ($urlAtual == $palavra) {
      echo "<html do $palavra SELECIONADO>".PHP_EOL;
   } else {
      echo "<html do $palavra>".PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/3LKMo9)**.

Comment: sim, consegui `$urlAtual = $urlE[1];
 for ($i=0; $i < 26; $i++){
  $letra = Chr(97+$i);
  if($urlAtual = $letra){
   if(isset($urlE[1]) && $urlE[1] == $letra){
    echo "<li><a href='".$urlBase."/filtragem/".$letra."' class='ativo' style='text-transform:capitalize;'>".$urlAtual."</a></li>".PHP_EOL;
   }else{ 
    echo "<li><a href='".$urlBase."/filtragem/".$letra."' style='text-transform:capitalize;'>".$urlAtual."</a></li>".PHP_EOL;
   }
  }
 }`, vc e fera, likezao

Comment: Procure entender o funcionamento, é importante para você melhorar seu código em outras partes no futuro. Não se limite só a adaptar, procure entender.

Comment: tenho mais uma menu, pelo que entendi essa linha `$letra=Chr(97+$i);` gera o alfabeto, como eu faria pra marca o menu que a url dele e assim `http://localhost/local/genero/acao`, como eu mudaria o valor `acao`

Comment: Pode usar um array de palavras e um `foreach` assim: https://ideone.com/3LKMo9 - atualizada a resposta